# How can I use a percent % in FormatString without it multiplying by 100?

Tags: c#, format-string

I would like to format an integer as a percent without it multiplying by 100 as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN#SpecifierPct).  Because my source is an int, dividing it first by 100 is not a valid option.  Is this possible?

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:#%}")]
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can escape the `%` character:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = @"{0:#\%}")]
```

---

Note that there are two ways to use `\` as an escape character: if you prefix a string literal with the verbatim symbol (`@`), then `\` characters are included in the string as-is, which means that as part of a format string a **single** `\` will function as an escape character.

Without the `@` verbatim symbol, `\`s are interpreted as escape strings *by the compiler* and as such need to be escaped themselves, as `\\`.

Pick one or the other, but not both:

```
@"{0:#\%}"  -> right
"{0:#\\%}"  -> right
@"{0:#\\%}" -> wrong
```

Comment: It is workinig fine for non-zero values but when value is zero(0) then only % is showing up. Any help?

Comment: Solved myself with this `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = @"{0:#0.##\%}")]`

Comment: The problem with this can be that you've now lost culture awareness of your formatting

Comment: @xr280xr That's what I was thinking too; I'm surprised more people haven't noticed that. For example, in Turkish the % sign is put *before* the number and some languages have different spacing rules for percentages.

Answer (score 37):

Put the % outside the {0:..}

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.00}%")]
```

Comment: @cadmium It's not voted higher, because you cannot use it directly on  custom numeric format strings. What I mean by that is methods like `ToString()` will not allow the `{ }` expression, rather you can only provide the format part that is between `{0:` and `}` in the above solution. Methods like `String.Format()` are okay, however.

Comment: I think this is not the good answer. What if you value is not present? you will get a lonely % char inside you field.

Answer (score 6):

From your linked page:

\
Escape character

Causes the next character to be interpreted as a literal rather than as a custom format specifier.

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:#\\%}")]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the value is 0, the format **@"{0:#%}"** displays just a %. It should display 0%. So the correct format is

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = @"{0:#0\%}")]
```

There is an extra zero after the hash.