# Display decimal as percentage using DataAnnotation

Tags: c#, string-formatting, data-annotations

In my database I have a decimal value `15.0`...

But in my view it displays as `1,500.00 %`..

In my metadata for this property I have this:

```
[Display(Name = "B Percent:")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:P2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public Nullable<decimal> BPercent { get; set; }
```

How, in my view, do I get the value to display as `15.0 &`?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format works correctly - `15M` is actually `1500%`. To correctly display `15%`, the value needs to be `0.15M`. You should store your percentage values in range between `0` and `1`.

If you can't do that, a possible solution is [How can I use a percent % in FormatString without it multiplying by 100?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983868/how-can-i-use-a-percent-in-formatstring-without-it-multiplying-by-100).

Comment: Thank you for the link to other question.  That is exactly what I needed.